# Store generated pdf to path using php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to store generated pdf to selected path.

Below is my code

```
  $pdf    = salesorder_pdf($salesorder);            
  ob_start();
  $attach=$pdf->Output($salesorder_number . '.pdf', 'S');
  $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/uploads/salesorder_pdf/'.$id . '/';
  if (!file_exists($path)) {
            mkdir($path);
            fopen($path . 'index.html', 'w');
        }
   $filename    = unique_filename($path, $attach);
  $newFilePath = $path . $filename;

  file_put_contents($path.$salesorder_number .rand(). '.pdf', $pdf->Output($salesorder_number . 
  '.pdf', 'I'));
  ob_end_clean();
```

pdf generation code

```
  function salesorder_pdf(){
       $CI =& get_instance();
       load_pdf_language($invoice->clientid);
       $CI->load->library('pdf');
       $invoice_number = format_salesorder_number($invoice->id);
       $font_name = get_option('pdf_font');
       $font_size = get_option('pdf_font_size');
       if($font_size == ''){
       $font_size = 10;
       }

       $selected_format = strtoupper(get_option('pdf_format_invoice'));
          $format_short = ($selected_format == 'A4' ? 'P' : 'L');
          $pdf            = new Pdf($format_short, 'mm', $selected_format, true, 'UTF-8', false);

          $pdf->SetTitle($invoice_number);
          $CI->pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, 26, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
          $CI->pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
          $CI->pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
          $CI->pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 30);
          $pdf->SetAuthor(get_option('company'));
          $pdf->SetFont($font_name, '', $font_size);
          $pdf->setJPEGQuality(100);
          $pdf->AddPage();
          return $pdf;
       }
```

Here when i try to store file has stored in path, but it's size become zero at selected path.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'F' and not 'I' for save file like:

```
file_put_contents($path.$salesorder_number .rand(). '.pdf', $pdf->Output($salesorder_number . 
  '.pdf', 'F'));
```

Comment: Try to use directly `$pdf->Output($salesorder_number . 
  '.pdf', 'F')`

Comment: Ok ,i got my answer.

Comment: Actually unique_filename() has mising,your answer also correct.

Comment: Can you flag how correct so ? we will help the other user to find it.

Comment: I am trying two types file_put_contents() and use direct $pdf->Output() and both are working for me.

Comment: So can you flag my answer?